# Extjs button in panel titlebar should look same like the button in toolbar

Tags: extjs4

In EXTJS 4.2, I am using a button in a panel's title bar and another button in toolbar.

Both the buttons look different.

Toolbar Button:
[image]

Title Bar Button:
[image]

Can anyone advise me to what I should do to make the look of the button in title bar same as the button in toolbar.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is a button in a title bar ? Are you talking about tools (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Tool). Some code would help others to help you.

Comment: Lorenz, yes title bar means tools. I want to display a button in the tools but its look and feel should be like the button in the toolbar.

Comment: Yes, this is what I understood, but 1. how to you place there the button ( show your code ). 2. Isn't the look of the header bar different from the toolbar anyway ?

Comment: tools: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Edit',
                icon: 'Assets/images/edit.png',
                style: 'margin-left:20px;',
                handler: function(event, toolEl, panel)
                {
                }
            },

Comment: Yes toolbar and tools in panel are different. But we can make both look same type by overriding css class.  Ok I am going to change my design and add the button in the tbar of the panel. Thanks Lorenz for looking into this for me.